# I need help showing the following integral evaluates to $0$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The integral is: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \sin (nt)\cos(n\xi) \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n\sin(n\xi)\cos(n\tau) \, d\xi$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting form your expression
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \sin (nt)\cos(n\xi) \sum_{m=1}^{N} a_m\sin(m\xi)\cos(m\tau) \, d\xi$$
You can exchange integration with the sums
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \sin (nt)\sum_{m=1}^{N}a_m \cos(m\tau)\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(n\xi) \sin(m\xi) \, d\xi$$
Now, you can demonstrate that the integral is $0$, for any value of $n$ and $m$ (I suppose they are integer, Am I right?). For demonstrating this fact, you can use the symmetric properties of the sine and cosine (one is odd and the other is even).

For computing the last integral, you can use the expresions for the sine of the sum of angles, finding
$$\cos(nx)\sin(mx)=\left[\sin\left((n-m)x\right)+\sin\left((n+m)x\right)\right]$$
Now, you can easily prove that 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}dx \sin(kx)=0,\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
And, hence, your original expresion is zero

Comment: Can you please help some more, I'm unable to get zero from this.

Comment: please, check out what I have added about this integral, and let me know if it becomes now clearer for you!

Comment: $a'_n\ne a_{n'}$ (and $n'$ is an awful choice of notation).

Comment: Thank you for the remark!. Actually you are right, it is a really awful notation: I have just changed it

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Exchange the order of summation and use the product-to-sum formula:
$$ \sin \alpha \cos \beta = \frac{1}{2} (\sin (\alpha + \beta) + \sin(\alpha - \beta))
$$

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to remark that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(n\xi)\sin(m\xi)\>d\xi=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(n\xi)\sin(m\xi)\>d\xi=0\ ,$$
since the  integrand is an odd function of $\xi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \sin (it)\cos(i\xi) \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j\sin(j\xi)\cos(j\tau) \, d\xi
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \sin (it) \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(j\xi)\cos(i\xi)\cos(j\tau) \, d\xi
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \sin (it) \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j\cos(j\tau)\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}(\sin((i+j)\xi) + \sin((j-i)\xi))\, d\xi
$$
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin((i+j)\xi) + \sin((j-i)\xi))\, d\xi = -\frac{1}{i+j}[\cos((i+j)2\pi) - \cos(0)] - \frac{1}{j-i}[\cos((j-i)2\pi) - \cos(0)] = 0
$$
(since $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$ )

when $i = j$:
one has:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}2\sin(i\xi)\cos(i\xi) \, d\xi  = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi }\sin(2 i\xi) \, d\xi  = -\frac{1}{4i} [\cos(4\pi i) - cos(0)] = 0
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \sin (it) \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j\cos(j\tau)\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}(\sin((i+j)\xi) + \sin((j-i)\xi))\, d\xi = \\ 
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \sin (it) \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j\cos(j\tau) \times 0 = 0
$$

Comment: $sin(j \xi) cos(i \xi) \not= (1/2) [sin((i+j) \xi) + cos((i-j) \xi)]$

Comment: lapsus, sorry. I wrote this without a paper just typing and thinking. Despite that the procedure is the same and I edited it already, thanks.